# Why does a single click generate multiple click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a `button` dynamically. But when I click it, it fires multiple `click` events and calls the associated function with `alert('clicked');` several times and not just one time.

Can you tell me why and how I can fix it?

**Code**

```
 var root = document.getElementById('current_page');
 var button = document.createElement('input');
 button.type = 'button';
 button.title = 'Add new book to list';
 button.className = 'btn btn-primary';
 button.id = 'get_new';
 button.setAttribute('value', 'No Thanks,Get New');
 button.setAttribute('style', 'position:relative; top:-5px;left:900px');
 root.appendChild(button);
```

**Handler**

```
$('body').on('click', '#get_new', function () {
            alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: I guess he asks why the function with `alert('clicked');` is fired more than once on a single click.

Comment: how to make it just to fire single click event..

Comment: post your HTML and a jsFiddle.

Comment: i have posted whatever i got!

Comment: The event will be attached one or more times. Please check it

Comment: Make sure you haven't add multiple handlers to some of the layers and also e.preventDefault() should help

Comment: Only once for me http://jsfiddle.net/M23Xv/. We need all the code to be able to verify why it isn't working. Or atleast a fiddle reproducing the error.

Comment: Why don't you try this instead: `$("#get_new").click(function() { alert('clicked'); });`

Comment: @josh
sometimes it does not work on dynamically created elements...

Comment: You need to bind your `click` function after you dynamically create an element.

Comment: @user3131402 your code is fine, see Danny's live demo. The issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: Are you using the same ID on multiple buttons?

Comment: @user3131402 see if the code below works

Comment: Is that just set on page load, or does something trigger it?  If the latter, is it trigger once on first click, twice on second, maybe 4 times on third, etc...?  It may be getting registered more than once.  You can check that the click event is not registered and if not, register it, otherwise, do nothing

Comment: yah!  you got it.! it it does behave in the same way. would u guide me hoe to fix it out? @Tom

Comment: @josh it worked , finally, u saved my life... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, you may as well create the element using jQuery and bind the click function on its creation. This will likely solve whatever is causing your double-firing issue.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f9PX4/

```
function myFunction() {
    alert('clicked');
}

$(function() {
    var button = $("<input>");
    button.attr("type", "button")
        .attr("title", "Add new book to list")
        .attr("id", "get_new")
        .css({ position: "relative", top: -5, left: 900 })
        .val("No Thanks,Get New")
        .addClass("btn btn-primary");
    button.click(function() {
        return myFunction();
    });
    $("#current_page").append(button);
});
```

Comment: This is not necessary. The OP's code actually works fine, and uses delegation which is a good practice.